# JTable custom cell renderer to create row header

Tags: java, jtable

Can somebody please explain how I would create row headers?  I already have the data and header texts set in the JTable: all I want to know is how I can use a cell renderer to take that first column (i.e. the row header column) and make it look like the column headers (i.e. the first row).  Right now its background is white, so it looks like regular data.  I want it to appear gray (or non-opaque I guess??).  Oh and it should also not be selectable.  Thanks.

I just realized that it should also remain put when scrolling horizontally, i.e. it should always appear on the screen even if there is a horizontal scroll bar.  Is this even possible?

**Update: ** I managed to get it to *look* like the row headers. But I am still not sure how to prevent scrolling.  Any ideas on how to prevent horizontal scrolling on the first column of a JTable?

Comment: Did I get you right you don't want to use the standard JTableHeader and would prefer using a custom renderer to make the 1st datarow also look like headers? Otherwise this would help http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html

Comment: Not exactly, the JTable has a default header ROW (horizontally accross the top). I want to keep this. But I also want a header COLUMN (vertically) (to appear in column index 0..the first column). Does this make sense?  And this header column, I want it to have the same look and feel as the default provided header row.

Answer (score 2):

I hate to answer my own question, but this allowed me to easily fix the first column:

http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/05/fixed-column-table/

Answer (score 1):

Something like the following should do it

```
table.getColumnModel().getColumn(col).setHeaderRenderer(new MyRenderer());
```